# How do I add a multiline variable in a honcho .env file?

Tags: python, environment-variables

I am trying to add a multiline value for an env var in .env so that my process, run by honcho, will have access to it.

Bash uses a '\' to permit multilines.  But this gives errors in honcho/python code.  How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Following [this documentation](https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tips.html#multiline-value) solved my case

I was adding value of .p8 file into a var in .env file, the file's format looked like:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
line1
line2
line3
line4
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Adding `\\n` at where you want to enter to a new line:

```
KEY='-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\nline1\\nline2\\nline3\\nline4\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----'
```

And in settings.py:

```
KEY = env.str('KEY', multiline=True)
```

check variable value by:

```py
print(settings.KEY)
```

Answer (score 1):

I put '\\' at the end of the line to permit multiline values.